# Use Linux commands for loop execute to resize a bunch of files. Errors

Tags: linux

I have created this command file. The purpose is to loop-execute a bunch of files and resize them from 8MB to 18MB.

Such files are `rubbi8.txt`, `rubbi9.txt`, `rubbi9.txt`, ... `rubbi18.txt`

My script is:

```
for i in {8..18}
do
  "truncate -s $im rubbi$i.txt"
done
```

The outcome is:

```
./kk3.sh: line 4: truncate -s  rubbi8.txt: command not found
./kk3.sh: line 4: truncate -s  rubbi9.txt: command not found
./kk3.sh: line 4: truncate -s  rubbi10.txt: command not found
./kk3.sh: line 4: truncate -s  rubbi11.txt: command not found
```

How can I configure the arguments for truncate command?

Thanks to jvb. The correct command format is:
--->
for i in {8..18}
do
  truncate -s ${i}m rubbi${i}.txt
done

Comment: What is the response to `which truncate`?

Comment: Click the check mark to accept an answer rather than editing your question.

Comment: Hi, Steven,

Do you mean that I add a vote up on the answers? I did that already.

Anything else should I do? I am new to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes around your truncate command and use curly brackets `${i}` to indicate the end of the variable name.

```
for i in {8..18}
do
  truncate -s ${i}m rubbi${i}.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The *quotes* will make `truncate -s  rubbi8.txt` (etc.) the *command name* - with spaces and parameters *as parts of the executable file name* - which does not exist.